# error with vtk package due to conda-forge

Tags: python, vtk, pyvista

i downloaded and installed 3d software from https://cadquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html, the problem which it caused is that im being unable to use pyvista bcs of vtk error. Before it ran correctly but after instalation this error arises while using package:

`vtkmodules.vtkFiltersParallelDIY2` is unavailable in some versions of `vtk` from conda-forge

ImportError: Initialization failed for vtkFiltersParallelDIY2, not compatible with vtkmodules.vtkCommonMath

The error arise when importing pymapdl package which is using pyvista(and vtk) and is hinting in jupyter lab that conda-forge might be the problem.

Just by using pyvista alone only the second import error message is alerted.

After instalation i thought that conda is installed but only for that software called _conda which has environment in temp forlder in appdata. I have no idea how to specify to python to search for vtk package from pip instalation instead of some conda.

Uninstalling wont work, and also tried to download anaconda for downloading vtk package but wont work either.

PIP
vtk 9.2.6
pyvista 0.37.0

anacoda
vtk 9.0.3

Comment: Where is your Python installation from? Do you have it installed separately, in addition to anaconda? Because if this is the case, and it used to work before, it's probably your `base` (or other auto-activated) `conda` environment that is broken. If the "pip" environment works, perhaps you just have to `conda deactivate` before trying to use the "old" env.

Comment: For posterity, this should have been resolved by https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/pull/4054 which is included in PyVista's 0.39 release